# Attempt of multimedia file transmission over DVB-T channel using Matlab Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, channel, transmission, dvb

I'm having trouble in Matlab Simulink model simulation. I'm trying to achieve transmission of a video file over DVB-T type channel in Simulink. I use the DVB-T demo of Matlab:

[Overview of Matlab DVB-T Channel Model from demo](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/examples/commdvbt_01.png)

But I can't achieve sending an actual file over this channel. I simply tried to replace "random integer" input block with the "from multimedia file" block, but as expected, I got input/output error, like this:

*Cannot propagate sample-based signal from output port 1 of 'commdvbt/From Multimedia File' to input port 1 of 'commdvbt/(204,188) Shortened RS Encoder' because this input port expects a frame-based signal. Consider inserting a Buffer in the signal path.*

I tried to use buffer with various settings, but couldn't manage to get this work. I did internet research, but couldn't find relevant information. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably got a matrix output from "From Multimedia File" block. The easiest way to use this in the same model is to convert this matrix into a single column and then use a frame conversion block to change frame mode of the signal to "Frame based". After that you will be able to use buffer block to get an output size of 188. Remember to account for any latency introduced because of buffer block when you are comparing the input and output.